# Classic ASP SOAP Request - Object reference issue pulling data from web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, soap, asp-classic

The error I see is: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Service.a(String A_0, String A_1) at Service.GetBuildings(String UserName, String Password)"

So it would appear my UserName and Password in my soap request are not being sent with their appropriate names (UserName & Password respectively), but rather being sent as A_0 & A_1 respectively. I'm not sure how to fix that - so I'm looking for advice.

My code looks like this:

```
<%
Dim objXMLHTTP : set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Dim strRequest, strResult, strFunction, strURL, strNamespace

'URL to SOAP namespace and connection URL
strNamespace = "http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/"
strURL = "http://myserver/EMSAPI/"

'function you want to call
strFunction = "GetBuildings"
'strFunction = "test" 'no parameters required

strRequest ="<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" &_
      "<soap:Envelope" &_
      " xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""" &_
      " xmlns:api=""http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API""" &_
      " xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""" &_
      " xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" &_
        "<soap:Body>" &_
                "<GetBuildings>" &_
                    "<UserName>Myusername</UserName>" &_
                    "<Password>mypassword</Password>" &_
                "</GetBuildings>" &_
        "</soap:Body>" &_
      "</soap:Envelope>"


objXMLHTTP.open "POST", ""& strURL &"", True

objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strRequest) 
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", strNamespace & strFunction


'send the request and capture the result
objXMLHTTP.send(strRequest)

'Set a timer to wait for response
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 t1 = timer()
 sleep(1)
 t2 = timer()
 response.write "waited "& t2-t1 &" secs"

 function sleep(seconds)
    if seconds>=1 then shell.popup "pausing",seconds,"pause",64
 end function


strResult = objXMLHTTP.responseText


'display the XML
response.write strResult

%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code to include 'xmlns="http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/"' in the GetBuildings node and it's working without issue now.

So the code looks like this now:

```
<%
Dim objXMLHTTP : set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Dim strRequest, strResult, strFunction, strURL, strNamespace

'URL to SOAP namespace and connection URL
strNamespace = "http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/"
strURL = "http://myserver/EMSAPI/"

'function you want to call
strFunction = "GetBuildings"
'strFunction = "test" 'no parameters required

strRequest ="<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" &_
      "<soap:Envelope" &_
      " xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""" &_
      " xmlns:api=""http://127.0.0.1/Integrics/Enswitch/API""" &_
      " xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""" &_
      " xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" &_
        "<soap:Body>" &_
                "<GetBuildings xmlns=""http://DEA.EMS.API.Web.Service/"">" &_
                    "<UserName>Myusername</UserName>" &_
                    "<Password>mypassword</Password>" &_
                "</GetBuildings>" &_
        "</soap:Body>" &_
      "</soap:Envelope>"


objXMLHTTP.open "POST", ""& strURL &"", True

objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strRequest) 
objXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", strNamespace & strFunction


'send the request and capture the result
objXMLHTTP.send(strRequest)

'Set a timer to wait for response
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 t1 = timer()
 sleep(1)
 t2 = timer()
 response.write "waited "& t2-t1 &" secs"

 function sleep(seconds)
    if seconds>=1 then shell.popup "pausing",seconds,"pause",64
 end function


strResult = objXMLHTTP.responseText


'display the XML
response.write strResult

%>
```